# Token is not revoked by calling wso2 revoke access API. Using WSO2 4.1.0

Tags: wso2, token, revoke-token

I am using wso2 4.1.0 and trying to revoke access token by calling WSO2 revoke API /oauth2/revoke. But able to use token even after revoke.

Checked the revoke access API response in saml and response seems correct. I am using wso2 4.1.0

Comment: Please explain a little about your deployment. whether it a distributed deployment or an all in one deployment, choice of KM, whether you are using the WSO2 IS or resident KM

Comment: Did you try this using the DevPortal? Did you try cUrl as well? Please try to access the API using cUrl and see whether it's the same behaviour.

Comment: @JoyRathnayake tried with curl command as well but didn't work. getting correct response in postman and saml

Comment: @Lakshitha I am trying to revoke the access token of users logged in using wso2 revoke API . but it doesn't revoke the token and user is able to use that token for calling other APIs

Comment: @Lakshitha we are using wso2 IS 4.1.0. can someone help here